# Integrating jQuery resizable with jquery.gantt

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to use jquery-ui's resizable component to customize the elements in [jquery.gantt](http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/).

Here is what I am trying to do in order change the size of a bar:

```
$('.ganttRed').resizable();
```

But the handles don't show. I have also tried specifying the option as well `{handles: 'e,w'}` but I haven't had much luck. I can use `draggable()` without any issues on the same element.

My jsFiddle skills are not very good; but here is one attempt to get you started

http://jsfiddle.net/BN8SY/1/

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time